# Modify image picker label from 'USE PHOTO' to 'CHOOSE'

Tags: ios, swift, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I have an app that either capture or pick image from gallery, the problem is that the client wants to change the label in imagepicker from 'USE PHOTO' to 'CHOOSE'

```
if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
    let showCamera = UIImagePickerController()
    showCamera.delegate = self as UIImagePickerControllerDelegate & UINavigationControllerDelegate
    showCamera.sourceType = .camera;
    showCamera.allowsEditing = false
    self.present(showCamera, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Unrelated but you should not need the `as UIImagePickerControllerDelegate & UINavigationControllerDelegate` cast. Just make sure your class declares that it conforms to those protocols.

Comment: noted on that @rmaddy thanks